# Angular: get a or li value on click

Tags: angularjs

i have a nice simple nav pills, i want to get a or li value on nav click

```
<div style="margin-left: 32px; text-align: center">
    <ul id="progress-view" class="nav nav-pills" >
        <li value="" class="active" style="margin-top: 15px">
            <a data-value="" data-toggle="tab">All</a>
        </li>
        <li data-value="505" value="0" style="margin-top: 15px">
            <a data-value="0" data-toggle="tab">New</a>
        </li>
        <li value="1" style="margin-top: 15px">
            <a data-toggle="tab">In Progress</a>
        </li>
        <li value="2" style="margin-top: 15px">
            <a data-toggle="tab">Waiting for answer</a>
        </li>
        <li value="3" style="margin-top: 15px">
            <a data-toggle="tab">Closed</a>
        </li>
    </ul>
</div>
```

thank you!!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
<ul id="progress-view" class="nav nav-pills" >
    <li value="" class="active" style="margin-top: 15px">
        <a data-value="" data-toggle="tab">All</a>
    </li>
    <li data-value="505" value="0" style="margin-top: 15px">
        <a data-value="0" data-toggle="tab"
           ng-click="clicked(0)">New</a>
    </li>
    <!-- etc... -->
</ul>
```

And your controller

```
$scope.clicked = function(val) {
    alert(val);
}
```

Of course, better would be to do it an angular way:

```
$scope.tabs = [{
    title: "All",
    value: null
}, {
    title: "New",
    value: 0
}, {
    title: "In Progress",
    value: 1
}]; // etc

$scope.tabClicked = function(tab) {
    alert(tab.value);
}
```

And in your view:

```
<ul id="progress-view" class="nav nav-pills" >
    <li value="{{ tab.value }}" style="margin-top: 15px">
        <a data-value="{{ tab.value" data-toggle="tab"
           ng-click="tabClicked(tab)">{{ tab.title }}</a>
    </li>
    <!-- etc... -->
</ul>
```

Comment: hey devqon, thank you for your replay, is it possible without sending a param? something like: var value = angular.element('#progress-view').data('value')?